# Get a reference to Gtk.OffscreenWindow cairo surface

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gtk3, cairo, webkitgtk

I am using `Gtk` and `WebKit` from `gi.repository` using python on X11 server (on raspbian).
I have a `Gtk.OffscreenWindow` with a `WebKit.WebView` widget in it and I am looking for a way to get a reference to the actual surface data of the `OffscreenWindow`.

`Gtk.OffscreenWindow.get_surface` returns a `cairo.XlibSurface` object but it doesn't seem there is a way to access pixel data of the surface (`get_drawable` is missing).

`Gtk.OffscreenWindow.get_pixbuf` returns a pixel buffer but to my understanding this is a copy of the actual surface data.

I used `get_snapshot` method of the `WebKit.WebView` but it creates a new `cairo.ImageSurface`.

My final goal is to use the reference to draw the surface using pi3d and get any surface updates without having to get a new snapshot of the `OffscreenWindow` (which is quite slow).

Comment: *Why* do you have a WebView in an OffscreenWindow? It sounds like you want to make the content of the WebView visible somewhere... well, then why is it in an OffscreenWindow?

Comment: I am using an OffscreenWindow because I want to make the content visible through opengl (pi3d).

Answer (score 0):

From the [GTK3 developer reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOffscreenWindow.html#GtkOffscreenWindow.description),

> GtkOffscreenWindow derives from GtkWindow only as an implementation detail. Applications should not use any API specific to GtkWindow to operate on this object.

`GTKOffscreenWindows` cannot or should not be operated on as windows, thus Cairo cannot be used on them.

Comment: I do understand the documentation. The purpose of the OffscreenWindow is to get a snapshot of the contained widget. You can get the surface with OffscreenWindow.get_surface which returns a cairo.XlibSurface as stated in the documentation. I am not using anything GtkWindow specific.

Comment: Why are you using a `GtkOffscreenWindow` at all? Couldn't you just have a virtual `WebKit.WebView` in memory, and get the surface? A `cairo.ImageSurface` would give you the pixel data anyway.

Comment: Yes this is indeed working. The problem is that get_snapshot creates a new cairo.ImageSurface every time you call it (as seen on webkit source). I am looking for a way to get a reference to a buffer that holds the pixel data, so any updates of the webkit content will be available through the same buffer.

Comment: I've never used WebKit before and I don't have time to look it up right now, but you do _not_ need the `GtkOffscreenWindow`. I would recommend connecting to whatever WebKit provides for a changed signal and using the pixel data provided in the `cairo.ImageSurface`.

Answer (score 0):

@kapetanos, You are probably familiar with the pi3d.groups conversation here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pi3d/4x0fPerYKRU
and the subsequent integration into pi3d
https://github.com/pi3d/pi3d_demos/blob/master/GtkCube.py and https://github.com/pi3d/pi3d_demos/blob/master/PyQtCube.py

I realize this is too late for your original question but it might help someone arriving here from a google search!

I still don't understand why the X11 drawing surface system that works on other linux implementations doesn't work on the Raspberry Pi but other developers seem to resort to using libbcm_host.so